# They are all tied together

Tags: word, lateral-thinking

There are four different things shown below

One Vertical

One Horizontal

Two diagonal

All have one common thing (the ? box) which ties them together

What is it?

[image]

Comment: Are the light grey lines a part of the puzzle, or is it just how you crafted the puzzle in Excel?

Comment: No they are not. I drafted on an EXCEL sheet. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All are

> Jumbled forms of famous internet domains (such .Com, ,edu, .Org, .mil)  - which are tied up through *WEB* - thanks to Omega Krypton

Hence the thing in the box should be

> .(a DOT)

Comment: internet for tied, thus the title. +1

Answer (score 8):

The ? box is

> the letter K

because

> each of the lines of letters anagrams to a word if K is added: DUKE, MILK, MOCK, and [GROK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok).

Comment: +1 for the anagram approach. But a simpler solution is hiding there with same approach!

Comment: @DEEM ... but this solution isn't ruled out by the question. If there is some reason (beyond "that wasn't what I was thinking of") why this doesn't solve the puzzle, it's not apparent at all what part of the puzzle actually invalidates this response. Because it seems this should be at least as valid as any other answer you might have in mind, this may be "too broad"—you may need to update the puzzle to make sure invalid responses are demonstrably invalid.